# Show elements in a list connected to selected element in another list with vue.js

Tags: html, .net, vue.js

When I click on a user in the first list, I want to get all the buildings in the other list that is connected to that user. 
I am able to get the user id when i click on the user, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get that id to the other vue app and to show all buildings depending on the user id.

My HTML file:

```
<div id="userApp">
                <ul class="collection">
                    <a href="#!" class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="user in users" v-bind:class="" v-on:click="toggleClicked(user)">
                        <!-- v-bind:class="active: isActive" -->
                        <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
                        <span class="name"><strong>{{ user.firstName + " " + user.lastName }}</strong></span>
                        <p> {{ user.phone }} </p>
                        <p> {{ user.email }} </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"></a>
                    </a>
                </ul>
</div>

<div id="buildingApp">
                <ul class="collection">
                    <a href="#!" class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="Building in buildings" v-bind:class="" v-on:click="toggleClicked(Building)">
                        <!-- v-bind:class="active: isActive" -->
                        <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
                        <span class="name"><strong>{{ Building.buildingName }}</strong></span>
                        <p> {{ Building.address }} </p>
                        <p>Byggeår: {{ Building.buildingYear }} </p>
                        <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"></a>
                    </a>
                </ul>
</div>
```

My js file:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#userApp',
    data: {
        users: [],
        newUser: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            address: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            isActive: false,
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.$http.get('/user').then(function(response){
            this.users = response.body;
        });
    },
    methods: {
        toggleClicked: function (user) {
            var changedData = {
                id: user.id,
                firstName: user.firstName,
                lastName: user.lastName,
                address: user.address,
                phone: user.phone,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password,
                isActive: !user.isActive
            }
            this.$http.put('/user/' + user.id, changedData).then(function() {
                user.isActive = !user.isActive;
            });
        },
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#buildingApp',
    data: {
        buildings: [],
        newBuilding: {
            buildingName: '',
            address: '',
            buildingYear: ''
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.$http.get('/building/').then(function(response){
            this.buildings = response.body;
        });
    },
});
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason not to make each of these apps a component and make an app that contains both?

Comment: no there's no reason not to make these apps a component. Would that help me show only the elements from the selected element?

Comment: Yes: the `selectedUser` should be a data item of the top-level app. It would be passed to the `building` component as a prop. The `user` component would emit an event when a new user is selected, and the top-level app would handle that event by updating `selectedUser`. I'll write this up in more detail as an answer when I have a chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your two apps become components with a common parent, the proper behavior is:

- The parent owns a `selectedUser` data item
- The `user` component emits an event when a user is clicked
- The parent receives the emitted event and updates `selectedUser` from  it
- The `building` component receives `selectedUser` as a prop
- The `building` component `watch`es `selectedUser` and updates its `buildings` data item accordingly.

The main app looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
  <user @selected-user="setSelected"></user>
  <building :selected-user="selectedUser"></building>
</div>
```

The snippet below demonstrates the behavior I've described.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedUser: null
  },
  components: {
    user: {
      template: '#user-template',
      data: () => ({
        users: [{
          firstName: 'First',
          lastName: 'One',
          address: '1 1st St',
          phone: '111-1111',
          email: 'one@example.com',
          password: '111112',
          isActive: false,
        }]
      }),
      methods: {
        toggleClicked: function(user) {
          this.$emit('selected-user', user);
        },
      }
    },
    building: {
      template: '#building-template',
      props: ['selectedUser'],
      data: () => ({
        buildings: [{
          buildingName: 'None',
          address: 'nowhere',
          buildingYear: '1969 - nice'
        }]
      }),
      watch: {
        selectedUser(newValue) {
          this.buildings = [{
            buildingName: `${newValue.firstName}'s building`,
            address: newValue.address,
            buildingYear: 'still 1969 - nice'
          }];
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setSelected(user) {
      this.selectedUser = user;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="user-template">
  <ul class="collection">
    <a href="#!" class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="user in users" v-bind:class="" v-on:click="toggleClicked(user)">
      <!-- v-bind:class="active: isActive" -->
      <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
      <span class="name"><strong>{{ user.firstName + " " + user.lastName }}</strong></span>
      <p> {{ user.phone }} </p>
      <p> {{ user.email }} </p>
      <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"></a>
    </a>
  </ul>
</template>

<template id="building-template">
  <div class="collection">
    <a href="#!" class=" collection-item avatar" v-for="Building in buildings" v-bind:class="" v-on:click="toggleClicked(Building)">
      <!-- v-bind:class="active: isActive" -->
      <i class="material-icons circle">folder</i>
      <span class="name"><strong>{{ Building.buildingName }}</strong></span>
      <p> {{ Building.address }} </p>
      <p>Byggeår: {{ Building.buildingYear }} </p>
      <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"></a>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <user @selected-user="setSelected"></user>
  <building :selected-user="selectedUser"></building>
</div>
```